# What are good C# Problems to solve for practice?

Tags: c#

I am still learning a lot of C#. And would like to hone my skills for future interviews. What are some simple C# problems to solve? The last interview I did had a pretty simple problem in it that I kind of struggled with, don't want that to happen again.

Comment: Are there any particular skills you wish to buff up? :)

Writing a game is always a good learning experience.

Comment: What kind of problem made you choke? Was it something arbitrary/nasty trick question, or something that would likely be encountered on the job?

Comment: It was actually something very simple. Which made me realize how little I know. They wanted a method where when you input d it printed out a multiplication table of column header times row headers up to D. for example if d=2, it would do a table with 1 times 1, 1 times 2, 2 times 1 and 2 times 2.

I eventually figured it out (albeit with some help from the interviewers). And when I got home I realized how simple it is and how easily I could have figured it out had I not been nervous. I want to do enough problems like these so I would be more confident the next time around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize this was 2 months ago, so you've probably become a C# master by now :)

But I've found the [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problems to be very nice. They are all math problems, and they aren't language specific. So they won't help you with C# per se, but they will help wrap your mind around different ways to solve problems.

Just as an example, the first question is:

> If we list all the natural numbers
> below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5,
> we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these
> multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3
> or 5 below 1000.

I won't give away the answer, but it's pretty easy to figure out with code if you think about it. Hope this helps and good luck.

-jb

Comment: At first it looked kind of complicated, but once I started working on it, it was very easy. Thank you :)

Comment: The Project Euler website looks like it's no longer available...

Comment: @DanEsparza that is not correct, I've been using it all month. http://projecteuler.net/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest checking out past problems from the ACM ICPC competitions. ACM ICPC is the granddaddy of all programming competitions.  But, if you like solve a problem a day you'll definitely hone your skills :)

here's the official website: http://cm.baylor.edu/welcome.icpc

And if you don't feel like navigating here's a quick link to this year's finals problem set: http://cm.baylor.edu/ICPCWiki/attach/Problem%20Resources/2010WorldFinalProblemSet.pdf

Great exercise for the brain. :)

Comment: oh, plus you should try googling common interview questions and solve those too! :)

Comment: The problem with those are that they're too advanced for me. I was thinking of starting out with much more simpler problems to begin with.
I am already reading other interview questions here on SO and on Google. But haven't found a good source of problems I can solve :(.

Comment: oh :( hmmm...well if you have any programming textbooks around, they usually have good problems to try in the back of chapters.  That's a good start. :)

I'll try to think of one that I own that's good enough to recommend. :)

Comment: Well here's a book you should look into:  Programming Interviews Exposed: http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/047012167X/books24x7com I've only skimmed through it, but it seems to be a good prep book.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some  [C # interview questions](http://www.skill-guru.com/test/43/c-interview-questions)

Answer (score 0):

UVa Online Judge has some nice problems but no submission for C# solutions although C/C++ is supported, Sphere Online Judge has some as well but those are mathematically oriented, although UVa is one of the biggest collections of problems, I guess you can write it in C# and test it against some of your own input or translate to C++ or Java and try it that way.